# Is 'window' not an identifier in Swift iOS Development?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am creating an iOS application. I have run into a problem: the identifier 'window' is unresolved.

This may be because I'm using the beta version of Swift and beta version of Xcode, but I need them to develop this app. I have tried searching other questions but none answer about the identifier 'window'.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    guard let splitViewController = window?.rootViewController as? UISplitViewController,
        let leftNavController = splitViewController.viewControllers.first as? UINavigationController,
        let masterViewController = leftNavController.topViewController as? MasterViewController,
        let detailViewController = splitViewController.viewControllers.last as? DetailViewController
        else { fatalError() }

    let firstMonster = masterViewController.monsters.first
    detailViewController.monster = firstMonster

    return true
}
```

I expect to be able to, in the end, select a menu item and have details show up on another View Controller, but I am getting an error with an unresolved identifier.

Answer (score 4):

> This may be because I'm using the beta version of Swift and beta version of Xcode

In iOS 13, and therefore in any new project created under Xcode 11, the `window` property is moved out of the application delegate and now resides in the *scene delegate*.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate

The `window` property is not formally part of the UISceneDelegate protocol, but it is part of the UIWindowSceneDelegate protocol:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowscenedelegate

In the new architecture, the window scene delegate instance is the locus of interface creation and maintenance, including access to the window, configuration of its `rootViewController`, and so on. The project template now includes a file *SceneDelegate.swift*, containing the declaration for SceneDelegate class which conforms to UIWindowSceneDelegate; here is the structure of the boilerplate code:

```
import UIKit
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    }
    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }
    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }
    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }
    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }
    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }
}
```

Your interface creation code should thus be moved into the scene delegate's implementation of `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3197914-scene

You will also want to move any `Active` or `Foreground`/`Background` code out of the app delegate and into the scene delegate. You should watch the WWDC 2019 videos on the multiple windows / multitasking under iOS 13, along with reading the docs:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_scenes